# Python script packed with cx_Freeze: how do I force windows to use an alternative console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, console, windows-console

I'm a very unexperienced programmer who has just began studying Python. I managed to do some basic stuff and now I tried packing my .py files to .exe files that can be shared with friends who don't have Python installed. I'm using python 3.4 so I was forced to use cx_Freeze which is pretty easy to understand, but I have a question:  is there a way to "embed" a different console than cmd.exe in those .exe's? 
I wrote some scripts that work only with command line, but window's console is pretty ugly and frustrating. I want my packed .exe to be opened with a more friendly console (even something like IDLE), is that possible? (everything must be packed in the final .exe, because this have to work even on an external pc that doesn't have python installed or a specific console installed).
Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: is there a reason this is only a command line tool? it may well be possible to open your finished program using a different console, but i would expect that to be quite awkward to bundle so that it always opens with the alternative console.if you are really worried about how it looks your best option would be to build a GUI for it, or make a second program to bundle with it (using python) that opens it and reads/writes to its command line and displays it on a GUI. that would give you much more control over how it opens and looks

Answer (score 0):

May be you should look to "py2exe" which is only build for windows.

I'm not sure at all you can embed "idle" in you "compiled" python project. If you need a more windows friendly presentation, I suggest you use wx python library which can be easily embed in your py2exe project.

see http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/ and http://wiki.wxpython.org/py2exe